# React Route With Params Location for route cannot be found

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Upon finding a solution for an issue I was having I came across another issue. After adding a route param on to my route, react router doesn't recognize it anymore.

Component rendering new route

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { hashHistory } from 'react-router'

class Name extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {username: ''};
    this.onClickFunction = this.onClickFunction.bind(this)
  }

  onClickFunction(e) {
    this.setState({username: e.target.value})
  hashHistory.push({
    pathname: '/level/' + this.state.username
  })
}

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-12">
          <div className="nameBox">
            <form className="form-inline">
              <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Desiered Username" onChange={this.onUpdateUser} />
              <button type="submit" className="btn btn-success" onClick={ this.onClickFunction }>Submit</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Name


import React from 'react'
import { Router, Route, hashHistory } from 'react-router'
import Home from './Home.js'
import Name from './Name.js'
import Level from './level.js'
import Level1 from './level1.js'
import Level2 from './level2.js'
//import result from './result.js'

const routes = (
  <Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path='/' component={Home} >
      <Route path='/name' component={Name} />
      <Route path="/level/:username" component={Level} />
      <Route path='/level1' component={Level1} />
      <Route path='/level2' component={Level2} />
    </Route>
</Router>
);

export default routes;
```

I'm new to React and this is my first app to help learn it. I already googled around and while widespread, the issue seems ambiguous. Any help would very much be appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of `this.context.router.push()` to send dynamic routes as well as the `event e` doesn't refer to the input but the button so `e.target.value` won't give the value of the input. You should implement the `onUpdateUser` function to update the state with the input value

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { hashHistory } from 'react-router'

class Name extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {username: ''};
    this.onClickFunction = this.onClickFunction.bind(this);
    this.onUpdateUser = this.onUpdateUser.bind(this);
  }
  static contextTypes = {
     router: React.PropTypes.object
  }

  onClickFunction() {
    this.context.router.push({
       pathname: '/level/' + this.state.username
    })
}
onUpdateUser(e) {
   this.setState({username: e.target.value});
}
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-12">
          <div className="nameBox">
            <form className="form-inline">
              <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Desiered Username" onChange={this.onUpdateUser.bind(this)} />
              <button type="button" className="btn btn-success" onClick={ this.onClickFunction.bind(this) }>Submit</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Name
```

Comment: Unfortunately the solution you posted renders the same issue with `http://localhost:3000/?#/'/level/'` as the URI, `Warning: [react-router] Location "/'/level/'" did not match any routes`

Comment: I meant to say try this `pathname: '/level/' + this.state.username`. check the updated answer

Comment: I did copy and paste your full answer that's rendering the error

Comment: I have edited the answer after you reverted back to me

Comment: The application renders the route partially with no route param then cuts rendering and re-renders a blank page. The console error is the same Location /level/ did not match any routes even though it was partially rendered.

Comment: try to use binding on the onClick function and e.preventDefault() as the page gets refreshed because of the submit action. I have updated the code again

Comment: Warning: [react-router] Location "/level/" did not match any routes (/w no partial load) Maybe going back to my original idea of using off site state management to store the state like Redux would work. Are you able to tell me what that looks like?

Comment: tell me are you not trying to press submit button without filling the input filed

Comment: I am filling in the input.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134982/discussion-between-quesurfin-and-shubham-khatri).